# Eclipse crashes on auto suggession

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I am using eclipse 3.7 (indigo) and it crashes every time i try to get the auto suggestion by pressing `Ctrl+Space`. I have even tried to change my eclipse and jdk version, but still getting the same error.

I am running on Ubuntu 13.04 and when i tried to run eclipse from terminal i got the following error -

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f4d744f2009, pid=21632, tid=139972060423936
#
# JRE version: 7.0_21-b02
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6e009]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x19
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/swapnilg/hs_err_pid21632.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/TujERyip) is the log file that i got. Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

it seems like there is [bug 404776](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404776) in eclipse  causing this. I had this effect on Fedora 19 with Eclipse Juno and Kepler. Problem is caused by newer version of libsoup.

There is a workaround which worked pretty well for me, just add

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

at the end of your `eclipse.ini`

BR,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

What Java versions have you tried? OpenJDK and? Did you consider using the Oracle's one?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle
java -version
```

Do you really need Indigo (3.7)? We have Juno (4.2) now... ooops Kepler (4.3) is just out.

Comment: I dont have a fast internet connection. Can u give me some other alternative. I have tried OpenJDK 6 and OpenJDK 7.

Comment: I don't have an alternative... What about using an Internet cafe?